# Bash IF check exact number is in the list

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to check if the number is in the list, but 23369 is matched with 2336953. I would like to know to match only exact number using IF in bash.

```
cgroup_uid="1251243 2007297 2336953 695212 834248 23369"
run_uid="1251243 2007297 2336953 695212 834248"
echo $cgroup_uid
echo $run_uid

for i in $cgroup_uid;do
if [[ $run_uid =~ $i ]]; then
    echo "contains $i"
fi
done
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Did you tried numerical `-eq`?

Comment: @geckos didn't work since $run_uid is a llist

Comment: I can use two for statements and compare each line, but wonder if can avoid two for statements it.

Comment: Something like `printf 'contains %d\n' $(printf '%d\n' $cgroup_uid $run_uid | sort -n | uniq -d)` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the elements that are in both lists:

```
comm -12 <(<<<"$cgroup_uid" tr ' ' '\n' | sort) <(<<<"$run_uid" tr ' ' '\n' | sort)
```

The `<<<"$cgroup_uid"` will output the variable with a newline. The `tr ' ' '\n'` will substitute each space with a newline. The `| sort` will then sort the numbers. The `<( ... )` is substitute for a filename that has the redirected output of the command inside. `comm -12` prints lines that appear in both files.

For how you are trying to do it, for comparison I would use `grep` words with `grep -w`:

```
if grep -w "$i" <<<"$run_id"; then
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in `$run_id` are guaranteed to be separated by spaces, you can use this:

```
if [[ " $run_uid " = *" $i "* ]]; then
```

Explanation: this checks whether `$i` is in the list, *proceeded and followed by spaces*. In order for this to work with the first and last elements in the list, we also need to add spaces to the list (i.e. `" $run_uid "`).